# flutter - scrollable left and right (card like) widget

Tags: android, flutter

So I have the following SwiftUI code and I want to now convert it to flutter.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                                        HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 10) {
                                            ForEach(self.lifeshows) { post in
                                                //return
                                                NavigationLink(destination: Podcasts(post: post)){
                                               
                                                 KFImage(URL(string: post.icon),  options: [.processor(ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: .init(width: geo.size.width / 4,height:geo.size.width / 4)))])
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .renderingMode(.original)
                                                    .frame(width:geo.size.width / 4, height:geo.size.width / 4)
                                                }
                                            }
                                            
                                            

                                        }.frame(height: geo.size.width / 4)
                                    }.frame(height: geo.size.width / 4)
```

I understand that it's not simple copy and past and the image (KFImage) will be different in Flutter (as I believe that can be handled by Flutter)

But can someone please give me a pointer in what the view will look like in Flutter as I understand Lists but how to make lists be scrollable left & right.

Comment: like this [horizontal list](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list) ?

Comment: hey checkout this following stackoverflow question with i have answered with bunch of blogs and tutorials help you to move forward,it easy to learn flutter with this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329221/website-youtube-channel-to-learn-flutter/64329394#64329394@RussellHarrower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter you can use

```
SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, child: ...)
```

or

```
ListView( scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: <Widget>[...]);
```

Comment: Thank you for that - just wondering tho can scrollDirection go into ListView.Builder?

Comment: Of course it can, it is the same widget but with a few different return functions